# What is the "guest" password?

Tags: terminal, macos, password, guest-account

I tried looking for the "guest" password by doing the command `dscacheutil -q user` and found the guest account. I saw that there was a "password" (I know that the usual guest account does not have a password) so may I ask what is the "guest password"?

Terminal output snippet:

```
name: Guest
password: ********
uid: 201
gid: 201
dir: /Users/Guest
shell: /bin/bash
gecos: Guest Account
```

By the way, I want to use my knowledge to show off Terminal's `sudo` without using login or su. (I do not want the commands `passwd` or anything similar from that)

Edit: As of El Capitan, the Guest user will output one star as below:

```
password: *
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The 'Guest' user does not have a password.**

The command you are using: `dscacheutil -q user -a name guest` always outputs 8 stars (`********`) no matter what password the user actually has set. As OS X only stores the hashed password, there is no easy way (besides using a password cracker) to recover passwords.

Edit: Hashed, not encrypted.

Comment: Actually the password is hashed (one way function) and not encrypted. Otherwise it would be possible to decrypt it (with the proper key).